# Java Mail Merge Application Compilation Error: "Illegal start of expression"

Tags: java, excel, ms-word, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm trying to run a small Java application that performs a mail-merge functionality on Microsoft Word documents using data from CSV/Microsoft Excel files. The goal is to replace markers in the Word document with data from each row in the CSV/XLSX file and create separate DOCX files for each row.

However, when I try to compile the Java file, I encounter the following error:

```
MailMerge.java:81: error: illegal start of expression
    private void applyLines(Data dataIn, XWPFDocument doc) throws XmlException, IOException {
    ^
MailMerge.java:82: error: illegal start of expressionn
    private void applyLines(List<String> headers, List<String> data, XWPFDocument doc) throws XmlException, IOException {
    ^
MailMerge.java:172: error: illegal start of expression
    private static void appendBody(CTBody src, String append, boolean first) throws XmlException {
    ^
3 error
```

This is the Java code I'm trying to compile:

```
package org.dstadler.poi.mailmerge;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.google.common.base.Preconditions;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions;
import org.dstadler.commons.logging.jdk.LoggerFactory;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTBody;
/**
 * Simple application which performs a "mail-merge" of a Microsoft Word template
 * document which contains replacement templates in the form of ${name}, ${first-name}, ...
 * and an Microsoft Excel spreadsheet which contains a list of entries that are merged in.
 *
 * Call this application with parameters <word-template> <excel/csv-template> <output-file>
 *
 * The resulting document has all resulting documents concatenated.
 */
public class MailMerge {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.make();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LoggerFactory.initLogging();
        if(args.length != 3) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Usage: MailMerge <word-template> <excel/csv-template> <output-file>");
        }
        File wordTemplate = new File(args[0]);
        File excelFile = new File(args[1]);
        String outputFile = args[2];
        if(!wordTemplate.exists() || !wordTemplate.isFile()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not read Microsoft Word template " + wordTemplate);
        }
        if(!excelFile.exists() || !excelFile.isFile()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not read data file " + excelFile);
        }
        new MailMerge().merge(wordTemplate, excelFile, outputFile);
    }
    private void merge(File wordTemplate, File dataFile, String outputFile) throws Exception {
        log.info("Merging data from " + wordTemplate + " and " + dataFile + " into " + outputFile);
        // read the data-rows from the CSV or XLS(X) file
        Data data = new Data();
        data.read(dataFile);

        // now open the word file and apply the changes
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(wordTemplate)) {
            try (XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(is)) {
                // apply the lines and concatenate the results into the document
                applyLines(data, doc);
        List<String> headers = data.getHeaders();
        for (List<String> dataRow : data.getData()) {
            // now open the word file and apply the changes
            try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(wordTemplate)) {
                try (XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(is)) {

                log.info("Writing overall result to " + outputFile);
                try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
                    doc.write(out);
                    applyLines(headers, dataRow, doc);

                    String newOutputFileName =
                            FilenameUtils.removeExtension(outputFile) + "_" + dataRow.get(0) + ".docx";

                    log.info("Writing overall result to " + newOutputFileName);
                    try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newOutputFileName)) {

                        doc.write(out);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void applyLines(Data dataIn, XWPFDocument doc) throws XmlException, IOException {
    private void applyLines(List<String> headers, List<String> data, XWPFDocument doc) throws XmlException, IOException {

        // small hack to not having to rework the commandline parsing just now
        String includeIndicator = System.getProperty("org.dstadler.poi.mailmerge.includeindicator");

        CTBody body = doc.getDocument().getBody();
        // read the current full Body text
        String srcString = body.xmlText();

        // apply the replacements line-by-line
        boolean first = true;
        List<String> headers = dataIn.getHeaders();
        for(List<String> data : dataIn.getData()) {
            log.info("Applying to template: " + data);

            // if the option is set ignore lines which do not have the indicator set
            if(includeIndicator != null) {
                int indicatorPos = headers.indexOf(includeIndicator);
                Preconditions.checkState(indicatorPos >= 0,
                        "An include-indicator is set via system properties as %s, but there is no such column, had: %s",
                        includeIndicator, headers);

                if(!StringUtils.equalsAnyIgnoreCase(data.get(indicatorPos), "1", "true")) {
                    log.info("Skipping line " + data + " because include-indicator was not set");
                    continue;
                }
            }
        log.info("Applying to template: " + data);

            String replaced = srcString;
            for(int fieldNr = 0;fieldNr < headers.size();fieldNr++) {
                String header = headers.get(fieldNr);
                String value = data.get(fieldNr);
        // if the option is set ignore lines which do not have the indicator set
        if(includeIndicator != null) {
            int indicatorPos = headers.indexOf(includeIndicator);
            Preconditions.checkState(indicatorPos >= 0,
                    "An include-indicator is set via system properties as %s, but there is no such column, had: %s",
                    includeIndicator, headers);

                // ignore columns without headers as we cannot match them
                if(header == null) {
                    continue;
                }
            if(!StringUtils.equalsAnyIgnoreCase(data.get(indicatorPos), "1", "true")) {
                log.info("Skipping line " + data + " because include-indicator was not set");
            }
        }

                // use empty string for data-cells that have no value
                if(value == null) {
                    value = "";
                }
        String replaced = srcString;
        for(int fieldNr = 0;fieldNr < headers.size();fieldNr++) {
            String header = headers.get(fieldNr);
            String value = data.get(fieldNr);

                replaced = replaced.replace("${" + header + "}", value);
            // ignore columns without headers as we cannot match them
            if(header == null) {
                continue;
            }

            // check for missed replacements or formatting which interferes
            if(replaced.contains("${")) {
                log.warning("Still found template-marker after doing replacement: " +
                        StringUtils.abbreviate(StringUtils.substring(replaced, replaced.indexOf("${")), 200));
            // use empty string for data-cells that have no value
            if(value == null) {
                value = "";
            }

            appendBody(body, replaced, first);
            replaced = replaced.replace("${" + header + "}", value.toUpperCase());
        }

            first = false;
        // check for missed replacements or formatting which interferes
        if(replaced.contains("${")) {
            log.warning("Still found template-marker after doing replacement: " +
                    StringUtils.abbreviate(StringUtils.substring(replaced, replaced.indexOf("${")), 200));
        }

        appendBody(body, replaced, first);

        first = false;

    }

    private static void appendBody(CTBody src, String append, boolean first) throws XmlException {
        XmlOptions optionsOuter = new XmlOptions();
        optionsOuter.setSaveOuter();
        String srcString = src.xmlText();
        String prefix = srcString.substring(0,srcString.indexOf(">")+1);
        final String mainPart;
        // exclude template itself in first appending
        if(first) {
            mainPart = "";
        } else {
            mainPart = srcString.substring(srcString.indexOf(">")+1,srcString.lastIndexOf("<"));
        }
        String suffix = srcString.substring( srcString.lastIndexOf("<") );
        String addPart = append.substring(append.indexOf(">") + 1, append.lastIndexOf("<"));
        CTBody makeBody = CTBody.Factory.parse(prefix+mainPart+addPart+suffix);
        src.set(makeBody);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what is causing this error, and I would appreciate some help in understanding and resolving it.

The Java code I'm trying to compile is the MailMerge.java file, and it includes the following functionalities:

- Reading data from a CSV or XLSX file.
- Opening a Word template file and applying the data from the CSV/XLSX
  file to replace markers in the template.
- Creating a new DOCX file with the merged data for each row in the
  CSV/XLSX file.

Could someone please review the code and help me identify the cause of the "Illegal start of expression" error? Any insights or suggestions on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You are trying to declare a method in another method. That can't work. Just look at the lines the error points to and it should be obvious.

Comment: Note that this question really has nothing to do with Excel or Word. When you encounter a problem, if you can't solve it after looking really carefully at where the error is, it's always worth trying to reproduce it in a smaller form. For example, it's easy to reproduce this error in about 6 lines: https://gist.github.com/jskeet/da3cc71d734ae0358754acde48a33345